# Click function not working in JavaScript console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I am trying to write a script because of which, when I click on one element in the list, all elements get clicked automatically.

But the thing is, I am trying to run it in the JS console.

And the console keeps throwing an exception that the `click()` function is not defined at `anonymous (some address)`.

I also tried the `trigger('click')` event. But that didn't work either.
I am assuming the problem is with the old version of jQuery.

Any idea what can I do to get a click on-all-at-once?
This is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var e = document.getElementsByTagName("Button");
  for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    e.onclick = e.trigger("click");
  }
});
```

This is the code for the banned names:

```
<div class="container_element sub_element hover_element">
<div class="wrap_element">
<div class="element_name">
<p>Drut</p>
</div><div class="delete_element delete_banned">
<button value="Drut" type="button">
<i class="remove_element close_room remove_private fa fa-2x fa-close">
</i></button></div></div></div>
```

This is the screenshot of what the list looks like:
https://ibb.co/T0cYVZ2

For those wondering why I am trying to do this:
I am basically a chat admin. There are over 2k banned people.
I can't manually clear all the bans one by one, it'll take centuries that's why I am forced to write this script. And no I don't have access to the DataBase or the hosting.

Comment: Your code does **not** use JQuery.  `getElementsByTagName` returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

Comment: Sorry. It was a format error.

Comment: `e` is a nodeList so it is impossible to attach an `onclick` direct to it... you probably want to `e[i].onclick  = ...` also call a `trigger()` direct to a node list won't work...

Comment: Ohhh yeah I forgot about that, my bad.
But the problem remains. I can't do anything if I can't simulate the click

Comment: please, post your current code, with no format errors or typos, then when we can see your real code we can help... Where's the function that you want to call when `trigger("click")` calls the click event? you can't attach the `onclick` event being the trigger of that onclick

Comment: My code is as is. The purpose is simple. One click on one button = all buttons clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already using jQuery you could do:

```
var $buttons = $('button').click(function(){

     // do something when it's clicked

     // trigger click on the others also
     $buttons.not(this).click()
});
```

Not sure why you would need to do this...seems unusual

Answer (score 0):

Add JQuery CDN as reference, enclose your *$(document).ready()* function with *script* tag and replace *e.trigger("click")* with *console.log("click")* like this -

hope it will help you.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var e = document.getElementsByTagName("Button");
    for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
      e.onclick = console.log("click");
    }
  });
</script>
```